# Как сделать так, чтобы при удалении inline-block - элементов они перескакивали наверх?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Суть вопроса: на картинке удалены несколько элементов. Всего в строке вмещается 5 элементов. Удаляю элемент через jQuery методом remove. Остаётся один элемент в строке, а нужно, чтобы он перескакивал на первую строку сразу после пред. элемента
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html:

```
<div class="descParams">
<table>
...
<tr class="addPhotoRow">
<td>
  <p>Фотографии <span>Вы можете прикрепить не более 5 фотографий</span></p>         </td>
<td>
    <div class="domPhoto greyBorder mainPhoto">
                          <div class=""><img src="img/dom2.jpg">
                            <div class="closePhoto visible">удалить</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="domPhoto greyBorder">
                          <div class="greyBorder"><img src="img/dom2.jpg">
                            <div class="closePhoto visible">удалить</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="domPhoto greyBorder">
                          <div class="greyBorder"><img src="img/dom2.jpg">
                            <div class="closePhoto visible">удалить</div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
...
```

css:

```
.domPhoto {
    position: relative;
    width: 142px;
    height: 77px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0px 14px 34px 0px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.descParams td * {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.domPhoto > * {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: легко и просто: задать фиксированную ширину второму td

Comment: Если вы сами нашли решение, опубликуйте его в качестве ответа

Answer (score 1):

```
.addPhotoRow td:nth-child(2){
  width: 873px
}
```

В моём случае нужно было просто установить фиксированную ширину ячейке таблицы (второй колонке строки addPhotoRow), в котором находятся элементы domPhoto. У первой также ширина фиксирована